# Drop Down Menu in Coco2d Game

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone, drop-down-menu

I would like to know if there was a way to integrate a drop down menu in cocos2d to spawn sprites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in a variety of ways. One way would be to have a menu sprite on top of the other sprites (via z order) and then change the menu item sprites positions with a `CCMoveTo` action so they pop down under the covering menu sprite and appear as a drop down menu.